# Javascript asynchronous looping with an external script

Tags: javascript

The ex.callAPI function is asynchronous and it is part of a external script. How can i pause the execution of the loop until each call to it is complete ?

```
for (var x = 0; x < apiuRLs.length; x++) {

result = ex.callAPI(apiuRLs[x])  //async call
//do somthing with result
}
```

Comment: `//do somthing with result` - you can't do that there - also you can't pause a loop ... need more info about the `ex.callAPI` function ... what does it **actually* return? is there a callback parameter?

Comment: If callAPI is a promise then you can simply use `ex.callAPI(apiuRLs[x]).then(function(response){ // do something with response })`

Comment: does `ex.callAPI` return a callback?

Comment: @RohanVeer - that wont "pause" the loop either

Comment: seriously, if you want help, you'll need to supply a lot more information about the `ex.callAPI` function

Comment: Yes it does return a callback. I dont need to necessarily use a for loop. I just need to iterate the apiURLs and call the api sequentially. the callAPI returns a json object.

Comment: why are you using async call if you want to pause the loop ? You can convert that async call to sync call.. what do you say @Jaromanda ?

Comment: If the call **returns** a object then it is **not** asynchronous at all

Comment: Async can not be made sync. Ever

Comment: `it does return a callback` ... `returns a json object` .... generally speaking, a function returns a single object/value .... you can't have both

Comment: My JS knowledge is very basic. Maybe i got it wrong. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how callAPI works. It it returns a promise, you can do something like:

```
var urlIndex = 0;
function next() {
    ex.callAPI(apiuRLs[index]).then(function(result) {
       //Do something with result
       if (urlIndex++ >= apiuRLs.length) {
         next();
       } else {
         done();
       }         
    });
}

next();
```

If callAPI takes a callback, you can do:

```
var urlIndex = 0;
function onResult(result) {
    //Do something with result
     if (urlIndex++ >= apiuRLs.length) {
       ex.callAPI(apiuRLs[index], onResult);
     } else {
       done();
     }         
}

ex.callAPI(apiuRLs[index], onResult);
```